# When is using the <appSettings> section preferable to a custom configuration section?

Tags: .net, configuration, appsettings, configurationmanager, custom-configuration

When creating my application's or library's configuration, I generally prefer using a custom configuration section over the `<appSettings>` section for the following reasons.

- Framework serialization to a user-defined configuration object; each config value has an appropriate type
- Configuration values may be validated against type and value ranges with attributes

Given this, when would I want to use the loose-typed `<add/>` key/value mechanism of the `<appSettings>` section?  As I recall, application-level configuration in this section can override existing machine-level configuration from machine.config.  Is this the only case, or are there other reasons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easier for quick-and-dirty applications.

It's the same reason ASP.NET has things like the magic "Page_Load" method - no explicit wiring, you probably don't use it in an enterprise-y application; it's just there for RAD.

Answer (score 1):

The appSettings tag has a "file" attribute that allows you to redirect your entire appSettings section to an external file. So for example you can have different appSettings instances for different environments: dev.config, qa.config, etc. I'm not sure if you can do that with other configuration sections though.

Example:

```
<appSettings file="qa.config"/>
```

Comment: You can do this with ApplicationSettings and configSource too.